# Margin on the first-line of a textField using iReport

Tags: ireport

I'm having some bad times with iReport since i'm trying to put some margin on the first-line of my text field.

Anyone did it before? What's the solution, i tried a lot of things what i read when i looking for answers.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

- Padding and Borders : **Padding** on **Top**
- Vertical Alignment
- Expression : `"\n" + $F{textField}`